# Cutting a section from a sphere by planes

Tags: graphics, constraint, computational-geometry

I want to plot and find out the section of a sphere remaining after putting constraints in terms of cartesian planes. How it can be done?

For example, if I have a sphere of $r = 1$, and I put the constraint $z > 0$ on it, simple imagination would suggest that it leaves half the sphere as defined by limits $\theta\in [0, \pi/2]$ and $\phi\in [0, 2\pi]$. Adding the constraint $x > 0$ leaves a quarter of the sphere with $\theta\in [0, \pi/2]$ and $\phi,\in [0, \pi]$, and so on.

I want to achieve the same using Mathematica. I want find the $(\phi, \theta)$ limits for more complex Cartesian constraints applied simultaneously, such as $x > y \land z > y$.

Will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

[**`ClipPlanes`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) does exactly what you need:

You can use `ClipPlanes` in two different ways:

(1) As an option to clip all the 3D primitives:

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/4], Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 2/3], Red, Sphere[]}, 
    ClipPlanes -> {{0, 1, -1, 0}}, 
    ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[.25, Gray]]
```

[image]

(2) As a directive that applies to individual 3D primitives:

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/4], 
  ClipPlanes -> {{0, 1, -1, 0}}, Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 2/3], 
  ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}, Red, Sphere[]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
{x, y, z} = {Sin[θ] Cos[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[θ]};

Reduce[0 <= θ <= π && 0 <= φ < 2π && z > 0, {θ, φ}]
```

> 0 <= θ < π/2 && 0 <= φ < 2π

```
Reduce[0 <= θ <= π && 0 <= φ < 2π && z > 0 && x > 0, {θ, φ}]
```

> 0 < θ < π/2 && (0 <= φ < π/2 || 3π/2 < φ < 2π)

```
Reduce[0 <= θ <= π && 0 <= φ < 2π && z > y, {θ, φ}] // FullSimplify
```

> (θ >= 0 && 4θ < π && 0 <= φ < 2π) || (4θ == π && ((φ >= 0 && 2φ < π) || π/2 < φ < 2π)) || (π/4 < θ < π/2 && (0 <= φ < ArcSin[Cot[θ]] || (φ + ArcSin[Cot[θ]] > π && φ < 2π))) || (π/2 <= θ < 3π/4 && φ + ArcSin[Cot[θ]] > π && φ < 2π + ArcSin[Cot[θ]])

For a graphical solution (to get a quick idea) you can do

```
RegionPlot[x > y && z > y, {φ, 0, 2π}, {θ, 0, π},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {φ, θ}]
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, you don't even need to specify the variables in `Reduce[]`. Using the OP's example: `Reduce[And @@ Join[{0 < θ < 2 π, 0 < φ < π}, Thread[{x, y, z} == {Sin[φ] Cos[θ], Sin[φ] Sin[θ], Cos[φ]}], {x > y, z > y}]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @J.M. yes. However, the use of `Reduce` and `Solve` with omitted list of variables is undocumented, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3}, 
{θ, 0, π}, 
{φ, 0, 3 π/2}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[1,
  {θ, 0, θf},
  {φ, 0, φf},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{θf, π/2}, 0, π},
 {{φf, π}, 0, 2 π}
 ]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the code you suggested can plot the section of sphere for given (phi, theta) range. Though my problem has another part, how to find the range of (phi, theta) when the sphere is sliced by certain plain by condition like x > 0. Thanks